# Skin vs theme, what is the difference?

Tags: user-interface

What is the difference between *skin* and *theme*?

I have looked at this articles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_%28computing%29
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_%28computer%29

and there is only one difference: *theme* is less "complicated" then *skin*. Like different set of icons and colors in *theme*, but *skin* can change UI control appearance (checkbox vs switch for ON/OFF control) in programmatic way which can be done by styling/CSS.

That difference in answer if it applied to WEB-app vs desktop application?

**UPDATE**. I have added the ability to change the look of the program via configuration file (icons, colors, element position). Is that skin or theme?

Comment: It's a subtle semantic difference, but not clear what you're really asking at present.

Comment: You should ask it on another StackExchange forum, like http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the difference is minor. My gut feeling says that I would call something which alters the appearance and feel of an interface a skin while I would call something which only alters the appearance a theme. A skin could add an extra button to allow for easier access to some of the underlying program's functionality, for example.

> I have added the ability to change the look of the program via configuration file (icons, colors, element position). Is that skin or theme?

That would be a theme (by my logic). In reality, though, most people will use the two terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

A **Theme** is a combination of multiple features that not only defines the layout of the website but also add additional features to your site. So a theme may consist of combination of skins and modules.

Whereas **Skin** is something that is purely related to your website appearance like it's color, block placement and other factors related to its layout.

> UPDATE. I have added the ability to change the look of the program via
>   configuration file (icons, colors, element position). Is that skin or
>   theme?

I would agree with @timgeb that you are actually configuring skin of your theme.